# Append new record in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets in a workbook,namely "MasterSheet" and "Operations". The data in the mastersheet is constantly changing whereas the data in operations is largely static.

I would like to be able to copy all records in column A in the master sheet if it does not exist in column A of the "Operations" worksheet. If it exists, it is simply ignored. I also need it to appear in the same order as it appears in the master sheet as well as copy columns B,C and D from the master sheet to the "Operations" worksheet.

If a record is deleted from the mastersheet, no data changes in the "Operations" worksheet.

How do i achieve this using VBA?

The version of Excel installed is 2010 and 2013.

** EDIT **

I tried with the following code and it doesn't work i.e. no records are copied. I also changed the worksheet names to 1 and 2.

```
Sub x()

    Dim r1 As Excel.Range
    Dim r2 As Excel.Range
    Dim r3 As Excel.Range
    Dim c As Excel.Range

    Set r1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set r2 = Sheets(2).Range("A1").Resize(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each c In r2

        Set r3 = r1.Find(What:=c.Value, MatchCase:=False, Lookat:=xlWhole)

        If r3 Is Nothing Then

            Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = c.Value

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a column with a `COUNTIF` formula to check if the item in `MasterSheet!A1` exists in the "Operations" sheet column A.  Then copy the formula down and filter on that column for 0's (does not exist in Operations), and copy the visible data from columns A:D

Comment: @tigeravatar ...using VBA

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to work with user on any code he's tried so far.  Right now he's asking that it be done for him which is not what this site is about.  So I gave him the steps he would need as a starting point.

Comment: @tigeravatar - I appreciate the help however if i am new to VBA and no idea on how to approach the problem

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - record a macro using the steps I provided.  That will give you a workable base to start with.

Comment: @tigeravatar - I gave that a go with no luck. I did rename my worksheets to 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the Range.AdvancedFilter Method? It may work for you.

into [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841242(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841242%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

In your requirement you did not specify the order sequence of the merged document just that the source (master data) values need to be in source order.  This will affect how you handle the combined sheet.  Adding a column to represent sort order with unique id's (ordered sequence of numbers) to both worksheets may be helpful.

**Assumption/Clarification**

- Column A represents a unique key for the data across master and operations data
- If there is a duplicate row between master and operations data there is no preference to which one you keep.  (e.g. other data in the sheet is always the same or irrelevant if different).
- both master and operations worksheets have identical column headings and ordering for the critera range selected
- no data below table of master tab, operations tab or destination tab

**Pseudo code**

1. name range for master database

   you can do this manually or automate it
2. count number of rows in master

   ```
   Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
   Dim masterRows As Long As Long
   Set masterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("master")
   masterRows = master.UsedRange.Rows.Count
   ```
3. name range for operations database
4. copy range for master to new tab

   ```
   Worksheets("master").Range("MasterDataRange").Copy _ 
   destination:=Worksheets("newMasterTabName").Range("A1")
   ```
5. copy range for operations to new tab underneath the master data (masterRows + 1)

   ```
   Worksheets("operations").Range("OperationsDataRange").Copy _
   destination:=Worksheets("newMasterTabName").Range("master.UsedRange.Rows.Count")
   ```
6. name new consolidated range (from the destination tab - s/b eqal to number rows master + number rows operations)
7. invoke AdvancedFilter on consolidated table

   ```
   Range("consolidatedNewMasterRangeName").AdvancedFilter _ 
   Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _ 
   CriteriaRange:=Range("Criteria") _
   Unique:=True
   ```

Once again, if you add a sort order to your Criteria so you have A,B,C,D,sortId you can use sortId after merge to reorder the list at intended.

My advise is to get it working using the gui first.  Then replicate in VBA.