# How do I compare two columns in different sheets for non existing values and then copy them to the main sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

Firstly, I am no expert with VBA, just searching for similar situation copying them, changing the code a bit and hoping for the best.

So I need to make a macro that compares two sheets. One of the sheets is the one that contains history information and all the specific names in Column A, where in the other sheet I paste daily information, where the specific names is always in column C and starts with row 7. The existing names could disappear or new names could be added and there will be duplicates.

What I need is for the code to first compare these two Columns for new names, if such are found copy them and past them in the history sheets A columns 2nd row, the existing names get moved down, so that they don't get deleted.

In short words saying If duplicate do nothing, else copy to history sheet.

Thank you in advance for all the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append new record in Excel using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250718/append-new-record-in-excel-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what your logic would be, but here are some VBA Pointers:

To compare columns in different sheets:

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ColRow").Value <> Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Col2Row2").Value Then...

Or you could replace the sheet names with (1) and (2) [or whatever order they are in the workbook].

For instance:
    If Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value <> Sheets(2).Range("C7").Value Then ...

Assignment to a cell works similarly. You can use a variable as an index:

```
Dim i1 as integer
Dim i2 as integer
i2 = 7
For i1 = 1 to 50
    If Sheets(1).Range("A" + CStr(i1)).Value <> Sheets(2).Range("C" + CStr(i2)).Value Then
        Sheets(1).Range("B" + Cstr(i1)).Value = Sheets(2).Range("C" + CStr(i2)).Value
    End If

    i2 = i2 + 1
Next i1
```